# CPU Upgrade Recommendations Thinkpad T480

Tags: processor, intel, upgrade

I have a Thinkpad T480 that has the stock [Intel Core i5-8350U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124969/intel-core-i5-8350u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html) vPro MB (1.70ghz) CPU in it.  It really just is not enough CPU for what I do with it once I dock it and hook it up to my dual monitors.  I haven't been able to find any information on compatible CPUs or if the upgrade is just plug and play or if its soldered.  I was thinking of upgrading to an Intel i7-9700 9th generation but I don't know if it is compatible or not.  Just hoping for a recommendation on what to purchase that will fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Ball Grid Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) used in the [Core i5-8350U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124969/intel-core-i5-8350u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html) CPU of the [Thinkpad T480](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/ThinkPad-T480/p/22TP2TT4800) is factory-soldered, and I would not even try to remove it to upgrade the CPU for any one of three choices:

1) Unsoldering and resoldering BGA CPUS is very difficult without factory-level tools

2) The chipset, also permanently soldered onto the motherboard, limits your CPU choices.

3) Laptops are very carefully designed to exhaust waste heat, and adding a hotter CPU likely shortens the lifetime of the other components. You're limited to 25W maximum [TDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power), 10W normal for safe operation.

**Alternatives:**

A) If you need more GPU, likely since the T480 relied on the Intel UHD Graphics 620 in the APU, an [external GPU device](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Graphics-Card/GV-N1070IXEB-8GD#kf) can be added, connecting via the USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C / Intel Thunderbolt 3 (Power Delivery, DisplayPort, Data transfer) interface.

B) You may also consider upgrading the PCIe (NVMe) drive, following instructions starting on page 69 of your [hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t480_hmm_en.pdf), if you are bound by drive performance. That would require finding the model of drive you now have before shopping for a [faster drive](https://www.windowscentral.com/best-solid-state-drives-increase-performance-windows-10), but Lenovo's tech specs for that device don't show that information. Therefore, I'd suggest (assuming Windows, since you did not mention Linux):

- Click "Start" and navigate to the control panel.
- Select "Systems and Maintenance."
- Click the "Device Manager," then "Disk Drives."
- You can get detailed information about your hard drive on this screen, including your serial number.